# In jqGrid the Delete Icon is not Clickable

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using jqGrid if I have a single row result and try hovering over the Delete Icon it will not receive the focus(is not clickable). I also have the search icon setting beside the delete icon and when I hover over it, it will not respond unless the cursor is to the extreme right of the icon so I figure that is the case with the delete icon but no mater where I place the cursor it will not react. It is like the hover action of the icons is somehow offset.

Comment: I don't see a question and I don't see any code.

Comment: You should verify that you included *all* required CSS files. You can find the corresponding example in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file). Typical error is missing of jQuery UI CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are doing inline editing (cell editing) or using the edit dialog box. If you are using the edit dialog, some things to check are that you have the following:
                  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
                      'cellEdit': false,
                      'cellDelete': false,
                      'cellAdd': false,

and then in the edit options, you can set the del or edit and the other icons:

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                      edit: true, add: true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false
                  },
                      // edit options
                      {
                          url: '@Url.Action("methodname", "controller")',
                          width: 250,
                          reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                          jqModal: true,
                          recreateForm: true,
                          closeOnEscape: true,
                          closeAfterEdit: true,
                          rownum: 20,
                          align: 'center',
                          editData: {
                              variable1: function () {
                                  return Var;
                              }
                          }
                      },